# PHP cURL json encoding - remove quotes around string of IDs?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm doing a post to an api, and building the cURL with php.

This is the php to compile the set of data to be sent:

```
$griddata = array(
  "agentId"=>'2',
  "categoryIds"=>$available_cat_id_list,
  "dateFrom"=>'2021-12-11',
  "dateTo"=>'2021-12-18',
  "propertyId"=>'1',
  "rateIds"=>$available_rate_ids_list
);
```

The two variables contain a string of IDs like this:
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

The data that gets sent looks like this:

```
{
"agentId":"2",
"categoryIds":"[15, 16, 17, 18]",
"dateFrom":"2021-12-11",
"dateTo":"2021-12-18",
"propertyId":"1",
"rateIds":"[7, 8, 9, 19, 20]"
}
```

This fails. However, it works when I manually add the two values without the quotes, eg:

```
"categoryIds":[15, 16, 17, 18],
```

How can I get the php to make the payload in that format?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like perfectly fine behaviour, if, as you stated, those "_contain **a string** of IDs like this_". Make those strings arrays and it should work just fine

Comment: Why do you put your list in a string, that then into a data structure which you turn into another string? BTW: Take the habit of extracting and providing a [mcve] before even asking here. You would have noticed that this has nothing to do with cURL at all! Also, spelling out clearly what you did, what you got and what you wanted (+why) could have lead you to the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a string in your variable, this string will be put to array and then encoded to json as string. If you want to encode it to json as array you should pass something that is an array:

```
$available_cat_id_list = [15, 16, 17, 18];
$griddata = [
    'categoryIds' => $available_cat_id_list,
];
```

If your data is already a string, you can extract it to array:

```
$available_cat_id_list = "[15, 16, 17, 18]";
//strip left [
$available_cat_id_list = ltrim($available_cat_id_list, '[');
//strip right ]
$available_cat_id_list = rtrim($available_cat_id_list, ']');
//explode by comma
$available_cat_id = explode(',', $available_cat_id_list);
//convert to integers
$available_cat_id = array_map('intval', $available_cat_id);

$griddata = [
    'categoryIds' => $available_cat_id,
];
```

Comment: Because the list of integers seems to be JSON, it's also possible to do `'categoryIds' => json_decode(available_cat_id_list),`, which is a shorter than this (still perfectly valid!) example and will also yield an array of integers.

Comment: @RickN - that did the trick, thanks so much!  How do I mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @AustenOsborne feel free to accept fsw's answer, my suggestion is merely a shorter way, his explanation—the 'why' this happens and the 'how' to solve it, by making an array out of the string—is more important than 'this is the shortest way to do it'. :-)